# What is use/benefits of Java InitialDirContext()?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I per my understanding it is used to add key-value pairs. 
But actually why we use InitialDirContext() and what are benefits we get from it and what are disadvantages of not using it?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are referring to this in LDAP context. if so, its not just adding key-val pairs & running operations on them. In LDAP context its connects & binds to sever... Once that is completed you can perform various operations as it provides object-oriented view of this directory, which means that Java objects can be added/updated in isolation to client.

Does that help?